# Conditions for Bragg-Gray Cavity theory

Tags: radiation, medical-physics

The conditions for applying the theory are, first, that the cavity of material $g$ has to be small enough, so that the cavity does not affect the incoming radiation to the material surrounding the cavity ( material $m$ ). The second assumption is more evasive. It says that the absorbed dose in the cavity is deposited entirely by charged particles crossing it.

In practice the cavity is an ion chamber, which contains oppositely charged plates that can collect charge. So when ionizing radiation enters the cavity it will decompose atoms into electrons and ions which will then collect onto the plates. Is this what the second assumption is talking about?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragg%E2%80%93Gray_cavity_theory